# PyQt4 window max size only registers after window move or resize by user

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qgridlayout

I'm constructing a GUI that is partially generated by QtCreator and partially by python code. The GUI is a grid layout scroll area inside a grid layout. The scroll area contains a variable amount of buttons. My goal is to resize the window to fit the button grid snuggly, unless there are too many buttons which make the window too big, in this case, I would like to limit the size of the window and make the scroll area scrollable. I achieved this, but there is a problem when the window is too big, **it shrinks to the desired dimensions only after I manually move or resize the window**. (Notice that the "show" and "resizeEvent" functions are overridden)

Image of the GUI:

[image]

QtCreator:

[image: QtCreator]

The python code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
import win32api

qtCreatorMainWindowFile = "map2.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorMainWindowFile)


class Map(QtBaseClass, Ui_MainWindow):

    NUM_OF_COLS = 30
    NUM_OF_ROWS = 30

    def __init__(self):
        QtBaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.window_max_width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0) * 3/4
        self.window_max_height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1) * 3/4

        self.buttons = []

        for row in range(self.NUM_OF_ROWS):
            self.buttons_row = []
            for col in range(self.NUM_OF_COLS):
                self.buttons_row.append(QtGui.QPushButton())
                self.buttons_row[-1].setText(str(col)+","+str(row))
                self.buttons_row[-1].setMaximumWidth(35)
                self.mapGridLayout.addWidget(self.buttons_row[-1], row, col)
            self.buttons.append(self.buttons_row)

    # Should only be called after "show" for geometry fields to be updated
    def resize_scroll_area(self):
        self.mapScrollArea.setMinimumWidth(self.mapScrollAreaWidgetContents.sizeHint().width() + self.buttons[0][0].x())
        self.mapScrollArea.setMinimumHeight(self.mapScrollAreaWidgetContents.sizeHint().height() + self.buttons[0][0].y())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if (self.width() > self.window_max_width) or (self.height() > self.window_max_height):
            self.mapScrollArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
            self.mapScrollArea.setMinimumWidth(0)
            self.setMaximumHeight(self.window_max_height)
            self.setMaximumWidth(self.window_max_width)
        return super(Map, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def show(self):
        ret = super(Map, self).show()
        self.move(0, 0)
        self.resize_scroll_area()
        return ret

# --------- Main code ----------
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
map = Map()
map.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please share the .ui file

Comment: .ui file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1jbdpw2k6kxgq2/map2.ui?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add these two lines to resizeEvent:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    if (self.width() > self.window_max_width) or (self.height() > self.window_max_height):
        self.mapScrollArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.mapScrollArea.setMinimumWidth(0)
        ######## Add these two lines: ########
        self.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.setMinimumWidth(0)
        #######################################
        self.setMaximumHeight(self.window_max_height)
        self.setMaximumWidth(self.window_max_width)
    return super(Map, self).resizeEvent(event)
```

The problem seems to be that, in this point in the code, **the maximum size of the main window was smaller then the minimum size**. Thus, setting the maximum size had no effect. Before the user resizes or moves the window, the minimum size gets updated somehow and the whole thing worked (remains to be researched - if someone knows how exactly this happens, I will be glad to hear)